# Pipe within a while loop

Tags: bash, csv, while-loop, bioinformatics

Let me preface this with an apology as I am certainly not a coder but in a position where I require the use of a .sh script (run in Git Bash on a Windows platform - work requirements) to develop a bioinformatics solution for my data.

I suspect my problem is pertaining to issues around parent and sub shell variables however there are a few anomalies. Firstly the script works when run minus the loop and not parsing a .csv file. If I have `done < test.csv` located directly after the echo commands the script works perfectly for the last line in my .csv file but does not produce output files for the other lines. However if `done < test.csv` is located at the end of my script it generates the required files, renames then and moves them (and even contains the user variable and sample variable from the loop) however they are nearly all empty of data.

Any assistance would be most appreciated. I have painstakingly read over many related questions however I have failed to implement their solutions successfully.

Example .csv;

```
Sample,F_index,R_index
One,dog,cat
Two,dog,cat
Three,cat,dog
```

Code;

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello - what is your input file, including file type?"
read -r var1
echo "Please enter user details (eg. name or initials)"
read -r var5

mkdir "$(date +"%Y-%b-%d")"
while IFS="," read -r Sample F_index R_index
do
    [ "$Sample" == "Sample" ] && continue
    echo "Sample : $Sample"
    echo "F_index : $F_index"
    echo "R_index : $R_index"
    grep -B 1 "$F_index" "$var1" \
        | sed "s/""$F_index""/&\\n/;s/.*\\n//" \
        | grep -B 1 --group-separator="$( )" "$R_index" \
        | sed "s/""$R_index"".*//" \
        | tee "$Sample"_trimmed.fa \
        && sed "/^\\s*$/d" "$Sample"_trimmed.fa \
        | sort \
        | uniq -c \
        | sort -nr \
        | sed "/^.*>/ d" \
        | tr -d " " \
        | sed "s/.*[0-9]/>&\\n/g" \
        | tee "$Sample"_deduplicated.fa \
        && sed "s/>//" "$Sample"_deduplicated.fa \
        | sed "/^[0-9]/{N;s/\\n//;}" \
        | sed "s/^\\(.*\\)\\(^[0-9]\\{1,4\\}\\)/\\2,\\1/" \
        | tee >(wc -l) \
        | sed 1i"Sample:,""$Sample""" \
        | sed 2i"User:,""$var5""" \
        | sed 3i"DATE:,$(date)" \
        | sed 4i"Frequency,Unique reads" \
        | tee "$Sample"_results.csv \
        | mv ./*deduplicated.fa ./"$(date +"%Y-%b-%d")" \
        | mv ./*trimmed.fa ./"$(date +"%Y-%b-%d")" \
        | mv ./*results.csv ./"$(date +"%Y-%b-%d")"
done < test.csv
```

Comment: That is way more pipes than I care to read through carefully, but: `"$( )"`? Pipes to `mv`? `tee >(wc -l) |`?

Comment: Wow, that's definitely searching out the limits of what you want to use bash for. Any chance you could get this rewritten in, I don't know, 10 lines of readable Python code?

Comment: What would the desired output be for input such as your test.csv ?

Comment: Most likely and I apologise for spamming it all here. Unfortunately I don't have time to get myself _up to speed_ with Python. I am in the process of trying to enlist the the help of a _real_ bioinformatician. I know enough to be dangerous..

Comment: @Vas - the variables from the .csv are used to interogate $var1 file which contains sequencing data. Basically I am trimming patterns and extracting unique sequences. A _real_  .csv and input file would look like the following; .csv- `Sample,F_index,R_index
One,ACATGAG,ACATCGC
Two,ACATGAG,ACATCGC
Three,ACATGAG,ACATCGC`                            
input file- `>M02181:40:000000000-D0L79:1:1101:14787:1659_1:N:0:1
TTCGTAGATGCGCCACGACTTGCAGCCTCCACGACTTCAACATGACCCGTCC >M02181:40:000000000-D0L79:1:1101:17930:1662_1:N:0:1
TTCGCCACCATGATTATGACCAGTGTTTCCAGTCCGTTCAGTTGTTGCAGTG`

Comment: Ok. This is quite complex to be handled with bash but in any case you can get useful debug info if you try to run it in debug mode. The way to do that is simply: 
    set -x   # activate debugging from here
    [do things]
    set +x   # stop debugging from here

Code does not show up properly in comments but you can find more about bash debugging mode here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

Comment: Great suggestion @Vas - I suspect I am nearly there;
`grep -B 1 --group-separator="$( )" "$R_index"`
is being interpreted as
`+ grep -B 1 --group-separator= $'ACATCGC\r'`
instead of `+ grep -B 1 --group-separator= ACATCGC`  

If I replace the variable directly with the pattern it works perfectly. Any suggestions as to the erroneous interpretation?

Comment: I am not sure your attempt to do this with a bash script is a good solution. BASH is designed to host programs and connect them, not to perform the actions itself, for instance sed is called multiple times, couldn't you reduce it to fewer calls?

Comment: What should the group separator be? Can you give an example? 
"$( )" would expand to just a blank space - i.e. it does not seem right.

Comment: OK - so the \r' tail on some of variables was in fact due to the DOS format of the .csv file. Running that through `dos2unix ./test.csv` sorted it all out.
@Vas - regarding the "$( )"  I am using it to remove the -- inserted between the lines following grep. I am sure there is a more elegant way to do it but it works for now.
@Llopsis - I completely agree regarding using BASH for this nature. It will be a useful tool in the interim but really it is a proof of concept to help persuade management and IT to allow higher end Unix machines for this purpose.

Comment: Two final comments - would Python be a suitable tool to handle this work? I am also not sure of the etiquette - Do I post the solution as an _Answer_?

Comment: @SDH it is encouraged to [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @muru What’s wrong with `"$(…)"`? It’s a pretty common pattern.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the ellipsis is misleading here. `"$( )"` would expand to nothing, since no command is given. Either there should be a command there or it should be in single quotes.

Comment: @muru Ah, indeed. I hadn’t seen that, I thought you were referring to the other uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, there are some specific and some more general problems in your code. The general problem is that instead of using proper, dedicated tools to solve problems, you’re re-writing these tools from scratch, in Bash, inefficiently, and naïvely.<sup>1</sup>

So, the solution to all your woes is: learn to use the existing tools. The first step for this is unfortunately to *find* those tools, and the best way to do this is to read methods papers and visit sequence analysis courses.

There are many to choose from; [here’s a small selection](https://www.biostars.org/p/174376/). But, for your specific purposes, I suggest using [cutadapt](http://cutadapt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide.html) for the adapter trimming and [biobambam](http://www.sanger.ac.uk/science/tools/biobambam) for deduplication — however, I generally recommend *against* read deduplication, as this will underestimate your expression signal.

---

<sup>1</sup> I’m saying “naïvely” but please don’t take this personally: it’s actually an impressive feat in Bash. But existing tools do a much better job at, for instance, removing adapters with sequencing errors, partial adapters, etc.; whereas your code will only find adapters if the *whole* adapter is present without sequencing errors. Your approach will therefore unfortunately fail in many real-world cases.